# Is there any modeless dialog in android, like what google maps shows when touched?

Tags: android, modeless

I want a widget that can interact with user, but will not block the activity ,just like google maps does when some place in the screen is touched.
Did any body know how to implement it?
I already know toast、alert,even activity with dialog theme ,seems that they all not meet my request.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe these are built using the [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) class.

Comment: oh,thanks ,I have tried it.But it seems it doesn't move with the POI(point of interest)

Comment: Hey, I dont have any experience with the class. I just know that you sometimes just miss the right keyword to find helpful resources, hence the short answer. Also, to help you, you have to post some code to see what you are doing (wrong). I guess opening a new question with the code is the best way here.